# Bitrix API изменить пользовательское свойство раздела

Tags: php, битрикс

Нужно изменить пользовательское свойство раздела (UF_MY_FIELD) в шаблоне компонента catalog.section.

Ранее я изменял только значения свойств элементов раздела, там буквально 1 строка.

Нарыл в инете вот такой код, но он не работает для меня :(
Код

```
<?
 $bs = new CIBlockSection;
 $IBLOCK_ID = $arResult['ID'];
      $arFields = Array(
         "UF_MY_FIELD" => "НОВОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ",
      );

      $bs->Update($data["id"], $arFields); 
?>
```

Что за переменная $data и $data["id"] тоже не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
global $USER_FIELD_MANAGER;
 
$aSection   = CIBlockSection::GetList( array(), array(
    'IBLOCK_CODE'   => 'clothes',
    'CODE'          => 'dresses',
) )->Fetch();
 
if( !$aSection ) {
    throw new Exception( 'Секция не найдена' );
}
 
$USER_FIELD_MANAGER->Update( 'IBLOCK_2_SECTION', $aSection['ID'], array(
    'UF_MIN_PRICE_SECTION'  => '117'
) ); // boolean
?>
```

Решение которое сработало для меня!

Answer (score 0):

`$data["id"]` - id раздела, в котором меняется свойство.

Но раз стоит задача менять свойство выводимого в `catalog.section` раздела, то Вы явно что-то не то делаете.

[Обновление свойства раздела в Битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/update.php)